# Эквивалент select fieldName, count(*) в LINQ вместе с join

Tags: c#, linq, count

Доброго времени, возникла необходимость обращения единожды к базе данных MS SQL, при этом нужно получить результат такого типа "Название поля, Кол-во всех строк с таким названием поля". с помощью последовательности вызовов расширяющих методов. 
Я смог сгенерировать такой код (есть собственные методы, коммент есть рядом). invoiceId - переменная, переданная в метод

```
var c = _repository.GetList<client_broker_invoice>(x => x.invoice_id == invoiceId); 
//получу Iquarable<client_broker_invoice> whare(x => x.invoice_id == invoiceId) 
//_repository.Query<> вернет: DB.Set<client_broker_invoice>().AsQueryable()
        var cc = _repository
            .Query<client_broker_invoice>()
            .Join(
                c,
                i => i.client_broker_id,
                o => o.client_broker_id,
                (i, o) => new
                {
                    brokerId = i.client_broker_id
                    //тут нужно количество записей где brokerId = i.client_broker_id
                });
```

Нужно как-то внедрить дополнительно в выборку количество записей, где brokerId совпадает. Можно ли это сделать до ображения к БД. Т.е. не делать так

```
var check = cc.ToList();
var note = new {Id = check.First().brokerId, count = check.Count()};
```

Запрос построен так, что он 100% возвращает записи, где brokerId у всех одинаковый

PS На sql я представил это так:

```
    select c1.client_broker_id as [brId], count(*)
from client_broker_invoice c1
join (select c2.client_broker_id
            from client_broker_invoice c2
            where c2.invoice_id = 205331) c3 on c1.client_broker_id = c3.client_broker_id
    group by c1.client_broker_id
```

в данном случае invoiceId = 205331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то что-то типа этого?

```
var result = (from c in _repository.Query<client_broker_invoice>()
              where c.invoice_id == invoiceId
              group c by c.client_broker_id into cg
              select new { BrokerId = cg.Key, Count = cg.Count() }).ToList();
```

Или ещё раз то же самое, но без linq-синтаксиса:

```
var result = _repository.Query<client_broker_invoice>()
    .Where(c => c.invoice_id == invoiceId)
    .GroupBy(c => c.client_broker_id)
    .Select(cg => new { BrokerId = cg.Key, Count = cg.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: а что в этом случае будет находится в cg? Select(cg => new { BrokerId = cg.Key, Count = cg.Count() })

Comment: В cg будет System.Linq.Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Grouping. Это как словарь, только с множеством элементов по одному ключу.

Comment: тогда cg.Key не прокатит, у нас же в cg словарь (т.е. элементов много)

Comment: Селектится только ключ и количество элементов с таким ключом.

Comment: В cg содержится информация об одной группе элементов. В Key — значение элемента, по которому выполнялась группировка.
Сперва попробуй код, потом скажешь получилось ли то что надо или нет.

Comment: aim, понял, спасибо вам, думаю это то что мне нужно.